# Play Framework app in Docker is not working

Tags: windows, docker, playframework-2.0

I have a container running a Play! Framework 2.4 stage app perfectly running in Ubuntu 12.04 host. After I achieved this, I try to migrate the container to a Windows 7 host following the instructions in the Docker docs web.

This container has Apache and MySQL running and those services are up and running nicely. I've run a bash terminal and check with pidof, ps and other programs the processes of the server and its running but no standard output, no log file, nothing is written and obviously the server is not responding.

I've mapped the port 9000 to 80 and to 9000 in my host machine and nothing happens.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I've checked that a newly app created with play new and then I've done a play run with it and it accepts requests to the server. However if I've stage it, the server doesn't start at all but the process is alive.

Comment: Up to now I've solved it making play start with code but this is not so good after all because the code is exposed.

Comment: can you give the command line used to start play ?

Comment: The project is named test, so I make inside the proect path: play start

Comment: Do you have any logs, docker file, something you can give that could give a clue ? you mention you tried a newly created app maybe share that. The recommended way to run a production server is through dist (see https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Production) the same page shows examples of command lines used to start the project, as you can see it shows some logs in the screen captures. so no stardard output seems fairly weird at least

Comment: The newly app is created doing: play new test. There I select Java app, test as name and then I do: cd test && play clean compile run. After this, I verified the app is up and running from a browser outside the container and is ok. After this I stop the actual play running app with Ctrl + D, and I execute play start. This last command starts the server in production mode. "play dist" is different from "play stage" in zipping the distribution, but it makes the compilation, library copy, etc, etc. as far as I know.

Comment: The thing is that a play dist or a play stage makes an executable that when I execute it no server response is acquired and no output at all.